# SQL Query to filter from an Array

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query

I wasnt sure how to title this question.

I have a database of suppliers, a simplified version is shown below.

| Company | Vehicles |
| --- | --- |
| X | ["Van", "Luton", "Artic"] |
| Y | ["Van", "Luton", "Rigid"] |
| Z | ["Luton", "Rigid", "Artic"] |
| A | ["Flatbed", "Hiab", "Artic"] |

I am looking for a way to write a query which will pull items based on the vehicle I am searching for...

I have a page where I can select a vehicle type from the a dropdown and the intention is to populate a table to show which companies have this vehicle but the way that it is saved to the DB `["x", "y", "z"]` is trippig me up slightly as I cant seem to use

`SELECT * From Table WHERE Vehicle = "input"`

Is there a way that I should write the query so that it can filter words from the vehicle string?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is a classic Data Normalisation failure.
You want to search by vehicle, but you've "buried" the vehicle data inside an array structure inside each record.  Sounds great but, as you've discovered, not so easy to do in the "Relational World".

- Relational Database are generally *very good* at finding little "bits" of stuff and bolting them together.
- They are generally pretty *rubbish* at finding big blocks of stuff and pulling them apart.

Short answer: Normalise your data which, in this case, means splitting these arrays out into separate rows in a new table:

```
select * 
from company_vehicles ; 

+---------+---------+
| company | vehicle |
+---------+---------+
| X       | Van     |  \
| X       | Luton   |   | This is the equivalent of your { 'X', ["Van","Luton","Artic"] } 
| X       | Artic   |  /
| Y       | Van     |
| Y       | Luton   |
| Y       | Rigid   |
| Z       | Luton   |
| Z       | Rigid   |
| Z       | Artic   |
| A       | Flatbed |
| A       | Hiab    |
| A       | Artic   |
+---------+---------+

select * 
from company_vehicles 
where vehicle = 'Artic' 
order by company ; 

+---------+---------+
| company | vehicle |
+---------+---------+
| A       | Artic   |
| X       | Artic   |
| Z       | Artic   |
+---------+---------+
```

Finding vehicles with *combinations* of vehicle gets a *little* more complicated, but it's all standard relational syntax.  For example, companies with both 'Luton's *and* 'Rigid's:

```
select company 
from company_vehicles 
where vehicle in ( 'Luton', 'Rigid' ) 
group by company 
having count( * ) = 2 
order by company ; 

+---------+
| company |
+---------+
| Y       |
| Z       |
+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks Phill. The problem that I have is, I have a database which contains over 1000 transport companies... When I add the company to the database, I also add the vehicles/services which the company offers which then saves the vehicles/services in the fashion mentioned above.
I wouldnt know where to begin, nor have the time to go through and sort out the database. Is there no way to query an array?

Answer (score 0):

`FULLTEXT` index.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT(vehicles);
```

Then use

```
SELECT ... FROM table
    WHERE MATCH(vehicles) AGAINST("+Van +Artic" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(Whether you need the `+` and/or `IN BOOLEAN MODE` depends on the details of your requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the vehicles field is stored as an array (MySQL [JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)), here is how the data can be queried:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    company VARCHAR(10),
    vehicles JSON
);

INSERT INTO supplier VALUES (default, "A", '[ "Van", "Luton", "Artic" ]');
```

You can search the vehicles field using the `JSON_SEARCH` function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM supplier 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(vehicles, 'one', 'Luton') IS NOT NULL;
```

This was using MySQL 8.0.34.

---

**Alternate scenario:**

Assuming the vehicles is stored as a string type:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier2 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    company VARCHAR(10),
    vehicles VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO supplier2 VALUES (default, "A", '[ "Van", "Luton", "Rigid" ]');
```

You can search the vehicles field using the `JSON_OVERLAPS` function. But, the input data must be in an array (as in the query below):

```
SELECT *
FROM supplier2
WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS(vehicles, JSON_ARRAY("Luton")) = true;
```